# Insert the text between two td's using class and Jquery is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to fetched the data from php using ajax and jquery and insert between two td using classname.
t1....t6 are class names
Expected Output:

```
    t1  t2 t3  t4    t5   t6
A   10  20  30  40   50   60 
B   20  20  10  20   20   10 
C   10  20  20  20   20   50
```

Actual Output:

```
  Bot_Code t1   t2  t3  t4   t5  t6
        A   10  20  20  20   20   50
        B   10  20  20  20   20   50
        C   10  20  20  20   20   50
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>

<span style="margin-right:150px">Bottle Name</span>
<span class="d5">Bottle Size</span>
<span class="d6">Bottle Type</span>
<span class="d1">Opening</span>
<span class="d2">Inward</span>
<span class="d3">Outward</span>
<span class="d4">Closing</span></th>
</tr>

<?php 
while($row_list=mysql_fetch_array($list)) 
{?>
<tr>

<td><a class="product" href="" myval="<?php echo $row_list['Bot_Code'];?>"><?php echo $row_list['Bot_Code'];?></a></td>
<td class="t5"><?php echo $row_list['Bot_Size'];?></td>
<td class="t6"><?php echo $row_list['Bot_Type'];?></td>
<td class="t1"></td>
<td class="t2"></td>
<td class="t3"></td>
<td class="t4"></td>

</tr>

<?php 
}?>
</tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
      var node=$(this);
    var item = node.attr('myval');  
  $.post('month_copy.php', {"bcode":item}, function(data){

  var products = data.split("|");
 $(".t1").text(products[0]);
 $(".t2").text(products[1]);
 $(".t3").text(products[2]);
 $(".t4").text(products[3]) ;
 }); 

});  

$('a').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Now, It shows the updated values in each row.I think there is something wrong.I tried to figure out didn't work.Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey good idea. but should set also an class or id-attribute to each row in the tr-tag.  $("#table.t1") means every dom element wich have the class t1. so I bet you should more do some thing like  $("#table #rowid .t1")

Comment: Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead

Comment: Pretty sure the code you've put here is not your actual code.  `#table.t1` would be element with 'id=table' *and* class 't1' ie `<table id='table' class='t1'>` which doesn't match your html.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Thanks, but didnt worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this -

```
node.parents('tr').children('.t1').text(products[0]);
```

Though if you can optimize HTML by adding a row Id, you can tweak the line to be more optimised

Comment: `.parents()` finds all the ancestors that match the selector.  While this would work with the limited HTML in the question, in practice it's possible (very likely if someone is still using tables-for-layout) that there will be multiple `tr`s.  You can use `.closest("tr")` to get the tr nearest/"closest" in the ancestor tree.

Comment: Agreed, with little tweaks to HTML and js, the overhead can be reduced greatly.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming your `#table.t1` is actually `#table .t1` (extra space).*

You need to specify which row you want to make changes to.

```
$("#table .t1").text("xx")
```

will change *all* elements with class t1 inside #table - ie all of the first column (as you've found).

What you need to be able to is:

```
thisRow.find(".t1").text("xx")
```

ie only find t1 inside the current row, which you can do with:

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

where 'this' is the element clicked, ie the `a`, giving you:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var node = $(this);
    var row = node.closest("tr");
    var item = node.attr('myval');  
    $.post('month_copy.php', {"bcode":item}, function(data) {

        var products = data.split("|");
        row.find(".t1").text(products[0]);
        row.find(".t2").text(products[1]);
        ...
    }); 
});
```